# Cannot install pysam

Tags: python, bash, pip, debian, pysam

I am attempting to install and use rmats2sashimiplot (https://github.com/Xinglab/rmats2sashimiplot) which requires several python dependencies installed as well. When trying to install pysam using pip, I am receiving the error "python setup.py egg_info" as seen in the screenshot below. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling setuptools on python. Any help is appreciated. Thank you. Note: I am working on a Debian bash shell on Windows 10, and I cannot use python or pip without typing "python.exe" or "pip.exe", so the command "sudo pip.exe" does not seem to be recognized even though I have added all the python directories to PATH.

[error-message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w69wY.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps it's this pysam Windows install issue? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60199392/3944171